# How do I stop folders being namespace providers by default in VS 2010?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, resharper

The subject kind of says it all.

**EDIT:**  I know this is a ReSharper related issue, and I know how to clear the `NameSpaceProvider` flag on a folder already.  My question is how to default all `NameSpaceProvider` flags to false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using Resharper?  If you're using Resharper you can right-click on the folder, and select "properties" from the drop-down menu.  The second property will be "namespace provider", which you can then set to false.

Hope this helps.

~ Cameron

Comment: This option in Properties window does not appear for me on any solution folder :(

Answer (score 0):

You will have that feature only if you installed Resharper. Default VS2010 IDE do not have that entry in folder's properties panel.